# Take hyperlinks and then copy from source to destination using hyperlink references

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

"Ok So modified the provided script and it is no longer skipping counting hyper links and is bringing in the right number of files now however it is duplicating pdfs for some reason. I have verified that each hyperlink is unique and the file names in the source locations are unique from each other.

Example below is a list that i tested this on. Originally my script would only bring in the first pdf in the list. Now with the updated script it looks at all the instances but duplicates the first PDF.

Sources its looking at.

```
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL-I.pdf
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HM.pdf
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HM-I.pdf
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HS.pdf
..\..\..\..\Cutsheets\Delta\Software\01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HS-I.pdf
```

What it pastes in folder. It uses same pdf and adds the row number to beginning. Its like its not reading the Characters in the hyperlinks past the HL.

```
01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

36-01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

37-01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

38-01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

39-01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

40-01 - Controller - Delta - DOW-340-HL.pdf

Public Sub CopyFile2()
Dim rng As Range
Const strNewDir As String = "D:\test\"

For Each rng In Range("L9:L1017").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  If CBool(rng.Hyperlinks.Count) Then
      With rng.Hyperlinks(1)
          If CBool(InStr(.Address, Chr(92))) Then
              If Dir(strNewDir & Replace(.Address, Chr(92), vbNullString, InStrRev(.Address, Chr(92)))) = "" Then
                  FileCopy .Address, _
                  strNewDir & Replace(.Address, Chr(92), vbNullString, InStrRev(.Address, Chr(92)))
              Else
                  FileCopy .Address, _
                  strNewDir & rng.Row & "-" & Replace(.Address, Chr(92), vbNullString, InStrRev(.Address, Chr(92)))
              End If
          Else
              If Dir(strNewDir & .Address) = "" Then
                FileCopy .Address, _
                strNewDir & .Address
              Else
                  FileCopy .Address, _
                  strNewDir & rng.Row & "-" & .Address
              End If
          End If
      End With
  End If
  Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll presume that you want to continue working with the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property.

```
Public Sub CopyFile()
    Dim rng As Range
    Const strNewDir As String = "D:\test\"

    For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If CBool(rng.Hyperlinks.Count) Then
            With rng.Hyperlinks(1)
                If CBool(InStr(.Address, Chr(92))) Then
                    FileCopy .Address, _
                      strNewDir & Replace(.Address, Chr(92), vbNullString, InStrRev(.Address, Chr(92)))
                Else
                    FileCopy .Address, _
                      strNewDir & .Address
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely.  If I want to use for a specific range would it be For Each rng In Range("L9:L1017").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: Also it seems to be skipping over some links in the list.  What would be the cause of that.  The links are valid and do take me to the desired pdf document when accessed.

Comment: What have you determined from debugging? What are examples of the hyperlinks skipped? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: I updated the code its like its not reading the full hyperlink string though in the range.